# Ignition gazebo citadel can no longer load worlds from fuel.gazebosim.org

Tags: gazebo-citadel, ignition-citadel

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 VM with Ignition Gazebo citadel, version 3.14.0 installed, I cannot load worlds from fuel.gazebosim.org.

Previously I was able to do so.

For example:

```
ign gazebo "https://fuel.gazebosim.org/1.0/OpenRobotics/worlds/Test_shapes"
```

was properly starting gazebo and loading the world (I could also do it with more complex worlds like the `Tugbot_warehouse`).

This command no longer works.
Now this command gives:

```
[Err] [Server.cc:181] Error Code 13 Msg: Directory doesn't exist[/home/ubuntu/.ignition/fuel/fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/openrobotics/models/ground plane/tip]  
[Err] [Server.cc:181] Error Code 13 Msg: Directory doesn't exist[/home/ubuntu/.ignition/fuel/fuel.ignitionrobotics.org/openrobotics/models/sun/tip]
```

And the same is happening with any other world from fuel that I tried. For every model, the "tip" folder is missing.

Is Gazebo Citadel still expected to work with Fuel? What would be the way to load Fuel worlds from Gazebo Citadel?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28699/ignition-gazebo-citadel-can-no-longer-load-worlds-from-fuel.gazebosim.org/) by [GuillaumeB](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2845/guillaumeb/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 45 on 2023-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a bug in Gazebo which should be fixed by https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-fuel-tools/pull/318

---

Originally posted by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) with karma: 704 on 2023-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1